# Relationship between set rewrite flag in register_post_type and add_rewrite_rule

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

In register_post_type, I can register a custom post type and set parameters, including rewrite. Based on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite, if it set to true, then the rewrite for this type of post will be handled.

Then I add some rewrite rules for the custom type of post by invoking [add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) in custom_rewrite_basic function.

However, on my tests, I find even I set rewrite to false, the rule set by add_rewrite_rule will still work, why?

Answer (score 2):

That's not what the `rewrite` argument of `register_post_type` means. If you set it to false, that doesn't mean "prevent any rewriting of this post type's URL, ever." That wouldn't even be possible.

It simply means not to use [pretty permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/introduction-to-blogging/#pretty-permalinks) when the post is created. You can still add rewrite rules for that post type later.

Comment: As a clarification, pretty permalinks are still possible, but the default ones core adds for your post type are not added when it is set to `false`. This does not prevent new rewrite rules that refer to your post type from being created, or ugly permalinks being used.